# Can django background tasks be deleted directly from the database?

Tags: django

We use django-background-tasks in our application and I have had no issue with deleting tasks from the admin page when running the app in my system. But when I tried to delete some tasks from the production version (hosted with gcp), I keep getting internal server (500) errors. What could be the reason for this?

**Alternately, is it advisable/safe to directly delete the tasks from the background_task table in the database?**

Comment: A 500 error has to do with your server side logic, but doesn't tell you much else. Please post your code and any additional error information, this is not enough to help you

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the tasks from the background_task table and it hasn't caused any issues.

The 500 could be due to some access issues (maybe some settings have to be configured to allow table modifications via admin page, over ssh?).